Using a lazy Provider with custom scopes for a injected Hilt object
I am able to get a custom scope skeleton project to work with Hilt. Here is the Hilt code below. All I really want to do, is add a lazy Provider wrapper as follows to the builder (or ultimately for the final injected object TestService):
Required lazy Provider:
@Singleton
class CustomComponentManager @Inject constructor(
    private val customComponentBuilder: Provider<CustomComponent.Builder>
) 

Existing working Code:
interface TestService {
    fun doSomething(): String
}

@CustomScope
class TestServiceImpl @Inject constructor() : TestService {
    override fun doSomething(): String {
        return "TestServiceImpl"
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(CustomComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @CustomScope
    @Provides
    fun provideScopedClass(): TestService {
        return TestServiceImpl()
    }
}

@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CustomScope

@CustomScope
@DefineComponent(parent = SingletonComponent::class)
interface CustomComponent {
    @DefineComponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): CustomComponent
    }
}

@InstallIn(CustomComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
interface CustomEntryPoint {
    fun getCustomDependency(): TestService
}

@Singleton
class CustomComponentManager @Inject constructor(
    private val customComponentBuilder: CustomComponent.Builder
) {
    private var customComponent: CustomComponent? = null

    fun createComponent() {
        customComponent = customComponentBuilder.build()
    }

    fun getComponent(): CustomComponent? {
        return customComponent
    }

    fun clearComponent() {
        customComponent = null
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var customComponentManager: CustomComponentManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        
        var customDependency: TestService? = null
        val customComponent = customComponentManager.getComponent()
        if (customComponent != null) {
            val entryPoint = EntryPoints.get(customComponent, CustomEntryPoint::class.java)
            customDependency = entryPoint.getCustomDependency()

            println(customDependency.doSomething())
        }
}

I get error:
Dagger/MissingBinding] dagger.internal.Provider<com.example.testcustomscopes.TestService> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,

What is the resolution?

The issue was that I selected the wrong import for the Provider. It is:
import javax.inject.Provider
